# Filling proportional circles with patterns instead of colors using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, mapping, fill

I want to fill proportional circles with a pattern like hatching or horizontal lines *inside the circles*, like in the image attached.

[image]

Can't find a way to do that with QGIS. Currently, I'm creating proportional circles according to a quantitative variable. I want to fill these circles according to a qualitative variable, not using colors but different patterns.

Do you know a way?

Comment: Could you add an image showing what you mentioned?

Comment: How do you create your circles currently?

Comment: Just edited my post to clarify it

Comment: So for each categorical value you want a different type of shading? Like if type="desert" you want yellow diagonals, or if type="rock" you want red horizontal lines etc? How many different categories have you got?

Comment: To be more specific, I have 4 categories (A, B, C, D), all can be crossed less A and D. So I would like to fill A and D with different colours, and B and C with different patterns/textures/structures, so I can cross A/B, A/C, B/C, B/D, C/D). Didn't explain that before because my first question is simply : how to fill proportional circles with patterns instead of colors?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html?highlight=lesson%20classification#basic-fa-classifying-nominal-data

Comment: The QGIS training manual does not learn how to fill proportional circles with patterns (and not colors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Filled Marker` with a `Line Pattern Fill` should work.

[image]